# Spring in Tomcat - what's lacking?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

As far as I'm concerned Spring is integrated in Apache Tomcat. Although, when trying to implement session beans, I've encountered an error

```
The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:scoped-proxy'.
```

on the declaration of bean:

```
<bean id="loginStorer" class="sef.inerfaces.service.LoginStorer" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

As I googled up, that may be because spring-aop.jar is not present in classpath. So, I guess I have to take it from a standalone Spring installation. My question is: am I right to do so, and if yes, what else from Spring is missing in Tomcat?

P.S. Tomcat is of 7.0.6 version.

Comment: Did you add `xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop` in `beans` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Maven for dependency resolution and build.

As for your assumption, it is incorrect. Tomcat does not bundle Spring out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This really looks like a problem in the spring context file where the namespace for aop has not been mentioned.